# How to inspect each payment in Mass Pay operation?

Tags: paypal, masspay

I want to send payments to users using Mass Pay operation, but I can't find how to inspect what payments received and what are not.

Here is text from www.x.com:

```
The response from a Mass Pay call signals only success or failure for the call, it does not
indicate the status of each individual transaction. To help account for your payouts, sign up
for the daily Transaction Details report, which collects the status of your individual 
transactions. You can also manually track your transactions by logging into your PayPal account 
to view the details and status of each of your Mass Pay payouts.
```

I searched for Transaction Details report, but I can't find exaple of using it.

How to send some call for Transaction Details report or some other way to inspect?

Comment: From the quoted text, it seems there isn't a *call* to retrieve individual transaction details of a Mass Pay call. Through you account, you may sign up for a report that you can view/download from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'listen' for Instant Payment Notifications (IPN's).

[IPN documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf)